# python install zope.interface module, show : AssertionError: Tried to end_progress without start_progress

Tags: python, pip, zope.interface

I use python ,and want to install module zope.interface in window 7, I used the cmd :

```
pip install zope.interface
```

but the console show :

```
Removing temporary dir c:\users\000790\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_000790...
Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 134, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 236, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1092, in prepare_files
    self.unpack_url(url, location, self.is_download)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1238, in unpack_url
    retval = unpack_http_url(link, location, self.download_cache, self.download_dir)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 622, in unpack_http_url
    download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 510, in _download_url
    logger.end_progress('%s downloaded' % format_size(downloaded))

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\log.py", line 98, in end_progress
    "Tried to end_progress without start_progress")

AssertionError: Tried to end_progress without start_progress
```

Please let me know if you have any workaround for the above error.

Answer (score 1):

Donwload from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.interface#downloads) the .egg of zope.interface and try this in CMD:

c:\Python27\Scripts\easy_install.exe c:\zope.interface-3.6.1-py2.6-win32.egg

NOTE: To install .egg, we need 'Easy Install' that is part of setuptools. So, we have to install setuptools first. Download it from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows).

NOTE 2: the .egg sometimes is unrecognised if it isn't on C:\ path